# Convert Metronome circuit to Visual Metronome (LED blinker)

Tags: transistors, oscillator, blink

I'm trying to make a Visual Metronome, i have a prebuilt one already (bicycle light) but it has a very high frequency of lighting up (2 flashes in 1 second).

I have a circuit for metronome, to which i added an LED, alongside the speaker, and it works fine, both the sound and light work as expected, giving 60 BPM output. (with change in C from 22 uf to 10 uf)

**Orignal Metronome Circuit:**

[image]

**Visual and Sound Metronome, by Adding an LED:**

[image]

Now, i am trying to make just a visual metronome from this, without the sound... That is, only with a blinking light, at 60 Blinks per minute...

The problem i am facing is that, if i remove the piezo speaker, i get a constant glow of LED, or get a blink in many minutes, and it only starts to blink correctly when i add the speaker back. I have tried adding a resistor across the LED, but that did not help.

I did see this question on EE, SE, and tried the circuit suggested by Jasen, but it didn't work for me... ( [3V LED Pulse Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323212/3v-led-pulse-circuit) )

So, i am wondering what alteration i need to make to the circuit, for the LED to blink, without the speaker added, to make it just a Visual Metronome, maybe with a couple of LEDs at a later stage.

**This does not blink or blinks in minutes:**

[image]

I do not have simulation experience, so i am unable to troubleshoot this with a program.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit has several problems, including the problem of rapidly draining the battery. At a minimum you need to swap the 2N3906 emitter and collector. As shown it *might* happen work, but if so then it will still be very inefficient. Also you need to put a resistor on the collector of the 2N3904 so power isn't shorted to ground when the transistors are on. Regarding the LED, you will need a series resistor if the LED's typical forward bias voltage is notably below the 3V (so it doesn't drain the battery unnecessarily) and a parallel resistor so that the output voltage is pulled low when the transistors are off, to provide proper feedback through the cap. I strongly suggest using a timer IC.

Comment: Yes, the metronome is a fully working circuit. I have made a few and even gifted them to friends. I will try the above points and see what happens.. TY

Comment: Reversing EC to CE on 2n3906 made the sound very faint. Also, a value of 20 Ohms on the collector of 2n3904 was the maximum i could use, after which the length of the beats became too short for use. Would a 20 ohms resistor be enough to save power (not shorting to ground)...?

Comment: When i add a parallel potentiometer on the LED, it dims the LED, otherwise it is bright... Also, i think the LED i am using is a 3mm LED, with operating voltage of 2.2V... It glows fine across the CR2032 battery. I am not going the IC way for now, as i have a learning curve to cross when it comes to transistors...

Comment: Reversing E-C should have made the sound stronger. Maybe the part is mismarked (a common occurrence). I do think this would be draining the battery, but it would also depend on the duty cycle.

Comment: It had become very inaudible by changing E to C on PNP.. Also, thanks for the suggestion of putting a resistor between PNP's B to NPN's C, i realised, the the short beat produced was equivalent of changing the capacitor value, a smaller value  of C made the beat shorter, just like increasing R between 06's B and 04's C... Hence, a small C could also save power...

Answer (score 0):

I found this circuit (use a larger capacitor for a metronome)in Google [www.circuitlab.com](http://www.circuitlab.com) :
[image: simple]